# web page width and height is smaller in mac pc than windows pc

Tags: css, windows, macos

Is px is different for mac pc and windows pc. How can I set same size for both mac and windows

```
   My CSS 
      .div
        {
         width: 900px;
         height: auto;
         margin-left:auto;
         margin-right:auto;
         margin-top: 1px;
         border: 0px solid #a3a3a3;
         overflow: hidden;
         background-color:#FFFFFF;
        }
```

Comment: The Pixel rendering is different on different browsers/OS.  It would not work the same if you use absolute values like 900px in your case.

Comment: Mansoor: In cases like this , you should set the width based on the absolute width (pixel rendering) of the screen on any OS.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Can you please give me an example I am really sorry for this simple questions. I am very new to web designing and css.